# How to hide a table when it blur/or click document that outside the table

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to hide a table when it blur/or click document that outside the table

Comment: Any attempts from your side? Best with code. Thanks.

Comment: I have made a date picker, it wrapped by a table elem. when user click the document outside the date picker, the date picker should hide, i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [event bubbling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) to your advantage here, like this:

```
$("#tableID").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).click(function() {
  $("#tableID").hide();
});
```

With [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) we stop the bubble from reaching `document` when it comes from *within* the table.  When it comes from *elsewhere* it (*by default*) gets to `document`, hiding the table.  In "by default", I mean you haven't done a`return false` or `.stopPropagation()` on those `click` events.

Comment: @Lucy this answer uses event bubbling...it the click event fires on the `#tableID` element first, then all the way up the parent elements until it reaches `document`.

Answer (score 4):

If you're asking how to hide the table when the user clicks elsewhere in the document (your wording is a little off), then may I suggest the **[clickoutside special event](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-outside-events-plugin/)** from Ben Alman?

Usage:

```
$('table').bind("clickoutside", function(event){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Or, if that seems a bit OTT, then try this (*no plugins required*):

```
var myTable = $('table');
$(document).click(function(e) {
    if (e.target !== myTable[0] && !$.contains(myTable[0], e.target)) {
        myTable.hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: IMO that plugin is tremendous overkill for a *very* simple problem :)

Comment: Just added an alternate solution. I agree tbh.

Comment: +1 for using $.contains(), pretty rare stuff. I would give you +2 if I could.

Comment: It should be noted that `$.contains()` is *much* more expensive, in every case but especially in older browsers then finding the element, and attaching a single handler. IE (including 8) for example doesn't support `compareDocumentPosition` which makes it even more expensive and recursive on *each* click event, rather than a one time (and cheaper even then) startup cost to bind it.

Answer (score 0):

Table have not blur, but elements inner table have:

```
$('#yourtableid:visible a').each(function(){
    $(this).bind('blur', function(){
        $('#yourtableid:visible').hide();
    });
});

$(document).bind('click', function(){
   $('#yourtableid:visible').hide();
});
```

This is jast idea, not solution